# If-Statement for the Login Button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010. I'm creating a login form and in the login form there is a combobox and a textbox. The items in combobox is the list of positions of the employees. Whenever a user click the login button there should be an if statement in the login button so that there are forms will open in a specific position of the employees. Please help.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

This is the code:

```
private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=timekeeping;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=admin;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        command.CommandText = "select username, password from users";
        connection.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            if (username_login.Text == Reader[0].ToString() && password_login.Text == Reader[1].ToString().Trim())
            {
                username = Reader[0].ToString();
                password = Reader[1].ToString();
            }
        }

        if (username_login.Text == username && password_login.Text == password.Trim())
        {
            this.Hide();
            Home form = new Home();
            //form.userSession(lname, fname);
            form.Show();
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Invalid User", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        connection.Close();
    }
```

I haven't included yet the combobox because I don't know what to put in here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Specific position' of the employees?

Comment: @jgemedina: For example: Individual employees, HR, Manager, Supervisor, etc... What I want is when I select HR, I will be directed to the form for the HR and when I select manager I will be directed to the form for the Manager.

Comment: @Abdul Muqtadir: I'm already done with the codes for opening a form when the username and password is correct.

Comment: without knowing the structure of your code, this is almost impossible to answer. How is your code structured? How is the login validated? What are the other forms called? Show us more information and we can probably help.

Comment: Do you mean, when an Employee is selected, a new Form will be displayed with their information inside it?

Comment: Question is bad formulated ,and there are some details which you shouldn't explain ,like 2 TextBoxes because we can see them .

Comment: @Alastair Pitts: I already put the code above.

Comment: @Paul Vitti: No. What I mean is that there are forms for every positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to reconsider your design:

It would be better if you stored the roles (position) of the users in the/a database.

If someone correctly identifies himself load the role(s) for that user and then open the correct form/application. Do not let the user select his role.

Have a look at [the Membership and Role providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354509.aspx) they're not just for ASP.NET, you can use them in Winforms as well:

Excellent set of tutorials:

- [Part 1](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2006/01/12/80905.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2006/01/13/80928.aspx)
- [Part 3](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2006/01/14/81014.aspx)
- [Part 4](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2006/01/15/81140.aspx)

Comment: No problem that's what we're here for.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following:

```
        Form mainForm;

        switch (comboBox1.SelectedText)
        {
            case "Individual employees":
                mainForm = new EmployeesForm();
                break;
            case "HR":
                mainForm = new HRForm();
                break;
            case "Manager":
                mainForm = new ManagerForm();
                break;
            case "Supervisor":
                mainForm = new SupervisorForm();
                break;
            default:
                mainForm = new DefaultForm();
                break;
        }

        mainForm.Show();
```

This uses a conditional statement called the [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx), which handles multiple selections by passing control to one of the case statements within its body.